# Expected number of matches when two people select characters from identical strings without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two people have given the same string, suppose : AB.  Both people pick one character at a time, so both characters either could be a match or not.  If a character is picked, then that will be discarded from their respective strings. 
For example:  P_1 : AB,   P_2 = AB.  If person 1 picks A then B and person 2 does the same, then there are $2$ matches.  If person 1 picks A then B and person 2 picks B then A, then there are $0$ matches.  Then answer is: $$\frac{2 + 0}{2} = 1.000000$$

so we have to tell, what is the expected number of times both people pick the same character.

Comment: Are the people choosing with or without repetition?

Comment: hi  N. F. Taussig, 
  there is no repetition while choosing the character, 
suppose, there are two persons have the string, P1 : AAA , P2 : AAA
since, both persons are picking one character at a time then their possible pick is ={AA, AA, AA}, 
so the total expected number of way is : (1*3+1*2+1*1)/3
 remember if the persons would pick the first character then that character will be eliminated from their respective string, and rest string after first pick would be : AA,  similarly they would proceed for rest of the character..

Comment: If each character in the string is different, then the answer is simply $1$, as you found in your example, although there are actually four cases in that example.  If the same character may be used more than once in a string, finding a general solution will be problematic.  On the other hand, if you use a specific word such as MATHEMATICS, an answer may be obtained.